PostgreSQLEnumJdbcType in Hibernate drop column
I have a class with enum:

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.hibernate.annotations.JdbcType;
import org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLEnumJdbcType;

import java.time.LocalDate;

@Entity
@Table(name = "t_tasks")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Task {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;
    
    @Column(length = 128)
    private String name;
    
    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @JdbcType(PostgreSQLEnumJdbcType.class)
    private TaskStatus status;
    
    private LocalDate date;
    
    @Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    private String description;
}


Also I have this jpa settings in my application.yaml file
spring:
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    show-sql: true
    open-in-view: false

When I start my application first (without any schema in db) time it logs next:
Hibernate: drop type if exists TaskStatus cascade
2024-12-23T16:41:50.599+02:00  WARN 5868 --- [TaskManager] [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Warning Code: 0, SQLState: 00000
2024-12-23T16:41:50.599+02:00  WARN 5868 --- [TaskManager] [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : type "taskstatus" does not exist, skipping
Hibernate: create type TaskStatus as enum ('DONE','IN_PROGRESS','TO_DO')
Hibernate: create cast (varchar as TaskStatus) with inout as implicit
Hibernate: create cast (TaskStatus as varchar) with inout as implicit
Hibernate: create table t_tasks (id bigint not null, date date, description TEXT, name varchar(128), status TaskStatus not null, primary key (id))
Hibernate: create sequence t_tasks_seq start with 1 increment by 50

And it works good.
But when I add some data to my db, stop app and run it again the next happens:
Hibernate: drop type if exists TaskStatus cascade
2024-12-23T16:44:55.688+02:00  WARN 21508 --- [TaskManager] [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Warning Code: 0, SQLState: 00000
2024-12-23T16:44:55.688+02:00  WARN 21508 --- [TaskManager] [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : drop cascades to 3 other objects
Hibernate: create type TaskStatus as enum ('DONE','IN_PROGRESS','TO_DO')
Hibernate: create cast (varchar as TaskStatus) with inout as implicit
Hibernate: create cast (TaskStatus as varchar) with inout as implicit
Hibernate: alter table if exists t_tasks add column status TaskStatus not null
2024-12-23T16:44:55.711+02:00  WARN 21508 --- [TaskManager] [           main] o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl     : GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "alter table if exists t_tasks add column status TaskStatus not null" via JDBC [ERROR: column "status" of relation "t_tasks" contains null values]

org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "alter table if exists t_tasks add column status TaskStatus not null" via JDBC [ERROR: column "status" of relation "t_tasks" contains null values]
    

and column t_tasks.status is droped and data is lost.
I use 3.4.1 spring boot version
Why does it happen and how to fix this without changing ddl-auto: update property

Don't use hibernate to manage your schema, even the hibernate maintainers don't suggest this. Use something like flyway or liquibase to manage your schema. That being said I would say your mapping is weird, either use @Enumerated(String) or a dedicated type but not both.
